# IKScannerDeviceView always uses a file based transfer mode

Tags: objective-c, imagekit, ikscannerdeviceview

I'm making a Mac application to scan multiple page `pdf` documents.

I'm using an `IKScannerDeviceView` and I set it's `transferMode` property to memory based so in the delegate I can get the scanned page as `NSData` and then add the page to a `PDFDocument`.

However, despite setting it to memory based, it still works as file based. After scanning, the scan gets saved as a file and preview opens up and I'm not able to get `NSData` in the delegate, only `NSUrl` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting that is known to be buggy.

refer to for possible flawed workaround: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/May/msg00727.html

Comment: I came accross that post while searching on google but i don't really get the solution. It seems to be not working after all.